# Military Grid Reference System Grid as Shapefile/FeatureClass

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules, mgrs

Is it possible to create a Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) Grid for a complete grid zone at a given precision level, for example 10km, as a Shapefile/FeatureClass with ArcGIS 10.4?

Comment: Did you had a try with the built in tools? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/page-layouts/adding-an-mgrs-or-a-u-s-national-grid.htm

Comment: Is it possible?  Of course. The only tricky part is clipping the edge tiles at the end of the UTM band.